# Elasticsearch index much larger than the actual size of the logs it indexed?

Tags: logging

I noticed that elasticsearch consumed over 30GB of disk space over night. By comparison the total size of all the logs I wanted to index is only 5 GB...Well, not even that really, probably more like 2.5-3GB. Is there any reason for this and is there a way to re-configure it? I'm running the ELK stack.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have lots of string content. String type is by default analysed, meaning that each string is split into tokens (from my little experience I found that the separators are " " and "-"), and each token is indexed.

Read more about string type [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html).

Now you know what you should be doing. The problem is that some tools offer very little support on how the information is sent to elasticsearch, thus making it very hard, if not impossible, to set the index attribute.